# Largest number a floating point number can hold while still retaining a certain amount of decimal precision

Tags: floating-point, precision

I would like to know the largest positive number a 32 bit float can hold while still being able to represent approximately 1/1000 decimal resolution.

So, for example if the float represents kilo Watts, how big can the kilo Watt number get before I would lose the ability to convert it to Watts without significant loss of precision (say a few Watts).

Comment: Do you mean absolute or relative resolution of `1/1000`? And do you need to represent positive values only? And for relative resolution, do you have a smallest value which should be representable?

Comment: Answers for this may differ if you want to know the largest number of watts an IEEE-754 binary32 can represent before there is too much rounding when the number is a number of watts versus if you want to know the largest number of watts a binary32 can represent before there is “too much” rounding error when the number is a number of kilowatts. That is because, if we are counting watts, 1, 2, 3,…, we can rely on there being no error until we get to 2^24 watts (16,777,216 watts). But if we are counting watts in units of kilowatts, .001, .002, .003,… there is rounding error at every step…

Comment: … and so that has to be accounted for. Additionally, it matters how these numbers are being calculated. The rounding errors are different if you calculate one added watt at a time versus if you add chunks of them. You need to state the details of the problem. Also, “a few Watts” is not a measure of accuracy. To do the calculations you are requesting, you need a specific target, like 3 watts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want the distance between two consecutive Float to be less than 1/1000 to have a precision of 1 watt or better.

This is related to the unit of least precision (ulp) of the Float.

In binary formats, the float magnitude has a general form `1.fractionBits * 2^exponent`

If the float has a precision p,

- its significand, composed by the leading one and the fraction bits, has p bits.
- there are p-1 fraction bits,
- the leading 1 represent a quantity 2^exp
- the first fraction bit a quantity 2^(exp-1)
- the last fraction bit a quantity 2^(exp-(p-1))
  this is the ulp of the float

Now the requirement is `ulp < 1/1000`. That is `2^(exp+1-p) < 1/1000`.

If we enforce the requirement a little, `ulp <= 1/1024`, that is 2^-10:

```
 exp+1-p <= -10
```

So the float exponent must be

```
exp <= p-11
```

For IEEE 754

- single precision, p=24, exp<=13, the float magnitude must be < 2^14, about 16384.0.
- double precision, p=53, exp<=42, the float magnitude must be < 2^43, that is about 8 * 10^12 approximately

Now, if you want a precision of a few watt, just do the arithmetic. 2 watts make the limit twice higher, 4 watts double the limit again, 8 watts etc...

We can generalize the formulation : if you want a precision of 10^-n, that is `2^(log(10^-n)/log(2))`, or `2^(-n*log2(10))`.

Thus the exponent must be `exp <= p - 1 -n*log2(10)`.

The limit is then `abs(float) < 2^(exp+1)`, that is `abs(float)<2^(p-ceil(n*log2(10)))`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write such a detailed answer.  The final number is much lower than I expected too!

Answer (score 2):

Certainly not elegant nor practical for `double`, yet with 32-bit `float`, easy enough to try various `float` values.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define limit (1/1000.0f)

int main(void) {
  float previous = limit;
  float next = limit;
  do {
    previous = next;
    next = nextafterf(previous, FLT_MAX);
  } while (next - previous <= 0.001f);
  //} while (previous + 0.001f > previous);
  printf("%.9g %a\n", nextafterf(previous,0), nextafterf(previous,0));
  printf("%.9g %a\n", previous, previous);
  printf("%.9g %a\n", next, next);
  puts("Done");
}
```

Output

```
16383.999 0x1.fffffep+13
16384 0x1p+14
16384.002 0x1.000002p+14
Done
```

So the previous `float` value to **16384.0** is at most a 1/1000 step and the next `float` value more than a 1/1000 step.

Comment: Brute force is always an attractive option :) I just wonder, maybe a modern CPU will consume even less than our brain to solve such small problem? Maybe not if we include edit-compile phase :)

Comment: For the fun, I asked ChatGPT what is the highest 32 bits float such that its precision is at least one per thousand? The wording in first part of the answer is almost correct, but then the computation goes wrong, leading to a 2^23 answer... Laziness does not always pay back ;)

Comment: Equally interesting, I then asked: Could you write a piece of C code that find this limit? It returns a solution starting at float max, decrementing the bits and using pointer aliasing instead of nextafter(), and using a wrong limit of 1000 instead of 1/1000.0, and comparing bits instead of float values, almost correct, but not yet there...

Comment: I have reported the chat GPT session here for the fun http://smallissimo.blogspot.com/2024/03/chatgpt-and-floating-point-intricacies.html

Comment: With the knowledge that all float in same binade have same absolute precision, we can infer that the limit lie at an exact power of two. This leads to a semi-brute force algorithm consuming less watts and even tractable in double precision.